# How can I install my webcam on Debian?

Tags: debian, compiling, kernel-modules, camera

I'm trying to install the webcam driver for my Logitech C210. After some googling Linux UVC driver seems to be what I need. I followed their typical use in hope to get it installed:

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git 
cd media_build 
./build 
make install
```

Now, I get these errors when I try to `./build`:

```
make -C /home/pi/media_build/v4l allyesconfig
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pi/media_build/v4l'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pi/media_build/linux'
Applying patches for kernel 3.1.9+
patch -s -f -N -p1 -i ../backports/api_version.patch
patch -s -f -N -p1 -i ../backports/pr_fmt.patch
patch -s -f -N -p1 -i ../backports/v3.1_no_export_h.patch
patch -s -f -N -p1 -i ../backports/v3.1_no_pm_qos.patch
Patched drivers/media/dvb/dvb-core/dvbdev.c
Patched drivers/media/video/v4l2-dev.c
Patched drivers/media/rc/rc-main.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/media_build/linux'
./scripts/make_kconfig.pl /lib/modules/3.1.9+/build /lib/modules/3.1.9+/build 1
Preparing to compile for kernel version 3.1.9
File not found: /lib/modules/3.1.9+/build/.config at ./scripts/make_kconfig.pl line 33, <IN> line 4.
make[1]: *** [allyesconfig] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/media_build/v4l'
make: *** [allyesconfig] Error 2
can't select all drivers at ./build line 451.
```

Btw im trying to do this on the Raspberry PI, architecture is ARM cpu.

Comment: This is looking for your kernel `.config`, which probably means you will at least need that to compile, if not the whole kernel source. But isn't this driver already included in the kernel? If you're building your own kernel, check under `Device drivers -> Multimedia support -> Video capture adapters -> V4L USB devices -> USB Video Class (UVC)`. This will require `Device drivers -> Multimedia support -> Video For Linux` (and that's probably required even if you compile the driver out of the tree). The module name (if you build it as a module) is `uvcvideo`.

Comment: got a clue on how to check that in terminal? im not running any desktop system :D

Comment: That is how to check it in the terminal, using kernel's `make menuconfig` menu-based *text* configuration tool. If you don't know what that is, then I guess you're not building your own kernel, and maybe there is some easier way to do it (well, just for a start, run `modinfo uvcvideo`, to be sure if there is really no module. If there is, `modprobe uvcvideo` will load it. if there isn't, I don't know if there is other way to install it in Debian other than recompiling the kernel (which is probably better than trying to compile out-of-kernel code when the driver is already in the kernel)).

Comment: Path has been chnged to `-> Device Drivers                                                                                                                 -> USB support (USB_SUPPORT [=y])                                                                                                     -> USB Gadget Support (USB_GADGET [=m])                                                                                               -> USB Gadget functions configurable through configfs (USB_CONFIGFS [=m])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [linux-headers](http://packages.debian.org/linux-headers) package in order to compile additional modules. This package contains the `.config` file and other files that are generated during the compilation of the kernel. Pick the version of the package that matches your running kernel.